# options for dealing with larger objects in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, visual-workflow

I have an object which holds about 45 fields.
That's not an awfull lot but still, if you are creating such records, you already need to do quite some scrolling on a mobile device.
I have been thinking about using a flow for this but I'm uncertain on how good this already works on Salesforce1.
Does anyone have some experience with this?
Or does anyone have other thoughts on handling a problem like this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the data you are gathering, Publisher Actions might be a good solution. It would allow you to narrow down those 45 fields to just the necessary ones for the mobile context.

The Salesforce documentation to get you started can be found [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/index_Left.htm#CSHID=actions_intro.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Factions_intro.htm|SkinName=webhelp)

Comment: Hi, all fields should be filled in from the mobile context.
The question however is, what would be the best way to have the users enter this information.
Hence the question if flows might be an option.

Comment: Hmm, still not sure visual workflow is the best option here. Perhaps a wizard optimized for mobile? http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/creating-a-wizard-with-visualforce-pages

Comment: Well, I'm not only looking at flows but wanted to see if someone already used this on mobile. And indeed if there are other suggestions they are more then welcome! Developing a mobile optimized visualforce page for it would also be an option yes.